# Autopopulated field doesn't work with forms

Tags: python, django

I have shop application, and in this app i have form that allow me to add comments under products, almost everything works fine but only when I add comments by admin panel, when I try add comment as user by form in my page, author column have value=None

[image]

Like you can see on this image when I'm trying to add comment as user by form in page, then field in column Nick which should show user who added this comment show only '-' but when i add comment as admin by admin panel then everything works correctly

models.py:

```
 class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(('1/5','1'),
                    ('2/5','2'),
                    ('3/5','3'),
                    ('4/5','4'),
                    ('5/5','5'),
        )
    nick=models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=None)
    content=models.TextField()
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
   published=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('published',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Komentarz wstawiony przez {} do produktu {}'.format(self.nick, self.product)
```

admin.py

```
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('nick','rate','product','published')
    list_filter=('rate','published')
    search_fields=('product__name',)
    date_hierarchy='published'
    ordering=('product','rate')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.nick = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def product__name(self, instance):
        return instance.product.name

admin.site.register(Comment, CommentAdmin)
```

form.py

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields=['rate', 'content']
```

Comment: You form not have a author field

Comment: Yes, but this is not editable field, so how i should add this field to forms if i want for this field to be automatically filled.

Comment: When i add author field then i have drop down list of all users to choose

Comment: Read the answer, you can set the widget to be a HiddenInput and then that field won't be displayed, just make sure you add an initial value for it when instantiating the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You form should have a field for the author, you could use a `HiddenInput` widget if you do not want that field to display.

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['rate', 'content', 'nick']
        widgets = {'nick': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

Then when creating your form in the view provide the `author` as an initial value.

```
def your_view(request):
    # ...
    form = CommentForm(initial={'nick': request.user})
    # ...
```

Comment: It's nothing, I'm glad to help comeback any time.

Comment: By the way, you have enough reputation points to upvote the answer, ;)